# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Assistance

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have set up a spreadsheet to manage stock in Google Sheets but I have a small problem, I want to set up conditional formatting based upon another cell.

Example

if A1 = "in stock" then A1 + B1 fill colour = green

if A1 = "out of stock" then A1 + B1 fill colour = red and text colour go white (so you can read it easily)

I know this isn't correct code but this I would like to happen in Google Sheets if possible. Also I would like it to span from range 1:1000 on those cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up two conditional formatting rules:

for range enter `A1:B1000`  and then for the rule on both you will choose custom formula.

1)     `=$A1="In Stock"`    and then choose your coloring choices and save

2)     `=$A1="out of stock"`  and then choose your coloring choices and save

[image]

[image]